# Access query - add column with subquery counter

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to add a proper "needCounter" column code to my query in Access.
It should count rows from 1 to "WorksPerWeekCounter" as it is shown in last, yellow column. Or better 0 to "WorksPerWeekCounter-1" :)

I find my code wrong because my "counter" does not correspond to my "counterMin"

Let's say I have a table [WORKS(roboczy)], and first 4 columns are just like below [https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTO53.jpg][picture] shows. (sorry, my reputation is too low to show pictures)

This is the Access query code I use (week2date function is in VBA code):

```
SELECT   
    W.Id_work, W.Id_pracownika, W.vecka, W.Rok,
    week2date(W.vecka,W.Rok) AS dataWK,
    C.countWorksPerWeek as WorksPerWeekCounter,
    C.Id_workMin as id_workMin,
    (W.Id_work- C.Id_workMin) as AddDays,
    DCount([Id_work],"[WORKS(roboczy)]","Id_work<=" & [Id_work]) AS counter,
    C.counterMin
FROM [WORKS(roboczy)] W
inner join 
( SELECT count(id_work) as countWorksPerWeek, Id_pracownika, vecka, Rok, min(id_work) as Id_workMin, min(DCount([Id_work],"[WORKS(roboczy)]","Id_work<=" & [Id_work])) AS counterMin
    FROM [WORKS(roboczy)]
    GROUP BY Id_pracownika, vecka, Rok
) C ON W.Id_pracownika = C.Id_pracownika AND W.vecka = C.vecka AND C.Rok = W.Rok
GROUP BY W.Id_pracownika, W.vecka, Id_work, W.Rok, week2date(W.vecka,W.Rok), C.countWorksPerWeek, C.Id_workMin, C.counterMin
```

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what the purpose of your counter variables are... Could you please clarify this?

Comment: I'll try to explain:

Comment: I have some number of rows [WorksPerWeekCounter] with the same date [dataWK] and [Id_pracownika].
But If there is more than 1 row i need to spread them for the whole week (randomly) counting from [dataWK]. The rest of counters I do not need.
So, [needCounter] should count rows of specific [dataWK] and [Id_pracownika] from 1 to [WorksPerWeekCounter], just to calculate later the days (0-6) I need to add to [dataWK]

Comment: I found it how to do it in more than 1 step: I just can add a temporary table to make a new Id_work by sorting W.Id_pracownika, W.vecka, W.Rok, then calculate min(Id_work) for each row with same date [dataWK] and [Id_pracownika] and deduct it from new Id_work in temporary table, that will give me the expected counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a series of subqueries in one step:

```
SELECT w.Id_work, w.Id_pracownika, w.vecka, w.Rok, w.dataWK,

(SELECT count(w2.Rok) FROM WorkCounter w2 
WHERE w2.vecka = w.vecka GROUP BY w2.vecka) As WorksPerWeekCounter,

(SELECT min(w3.Id_work) FROM WorkCounter w3 
WHERE w3.vecka = w.vecka GROUP BY w3.vecka) As id_workMin, 

w.Id_work - 
(SELECT min(w3.Id_work) FROM WorkCounter w3 
WHERE w3.vecka = w.vecka GROUP BY w3.vecka) As AddDays,

(SELECT count(*) FROM WorkCounter w4 
WHERE w4.Id_work <= w.Id_work and w4.vecka = w.vecka) As Counter

FROM [WORKS(roboczy)] W
```